# Как присвоить один стиль нескольким классам?

Tags: sass, scss, бэм

есть два класса

```
.product
   &__price--gold
       margin-bottom: 15px

   &__price--retail
       margin-bottom: 10px
```

они оба должны иметь сввойство **font-size: 100px**

я мог бы написать и так

```
.product
   &__price--gold
       margin-bottom: 15px

   &__price--retail
       margin-bottom: 10px

   &__price--gold ,&__price--retail
       font-size: 100px
```

но это долго , есть ли в припроцессорах какой то *способ* сделать это проще 
например как то так ?

```
.product
   &__price--(*)
       font-size: 100px
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Миксины и переменные.

Но, следуя идеологии БЭМ, обобщать **различные** сущности нельзя. В вашем случае свойство `font-size` скорее всего стоит вынести из модификаторов на уровень элемента.

```
.product
    &__price
        font-size: 100px;

        &--gold
            ...
        &--retail
            ...

<div class="product__price product__price--gold"> ... </div>
```